# Which curve is the best fit, in terms of having the same shape as the actuals series?

Tags: r, regression, goodness-of-fit, fitting, curve-fitting

I have a set of $N$ models that have generated simulated values based on theoretical assumptions (not regressions) for times $t=1,2,\dots,T$. I want to check which of these models has produced the best fit over this period (i.e. backward looking not forward looking) compared with the series of actuals. Important to note is that I am interested in which series mimics the "shape" (i.e. upward and downward movements etc.) of the actuals series the best, however, I am not interested in which series is actually closest to the actuals in terms of absolute distance (like Mean Squared Error would give me). I.e., a series could be very far away from the actuals at times, but as long as it moves in approximately the same way it is considered "good".

Of course I can visually inspect this, but I want to be able to base it on numbers. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this in R?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will help if you can be more specific about range of models in the set. Here's a simplified example - things only get more complicated from here. Assume that truth has one local minimum over a 1-D interval of interest. And assume the same for the models.  A metric of which is best could be the distance from the minimum of the model to the location of the true minimum. This could also be done in higher dimensions, with possibility of weighting per component. If multiple minima and maxima, then combine errors in locations. But what if you don';t know how many minima or get number wrong, etc.?

Comment: Have you thought about approaches (akin to the [Sign test](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/BS704_Nonparametric/BS704_Nonparametric5.html) ) where you reduce your data to binary increasing/decreasing trends (instead of absolute numbers), and then looking at something like concordant/discordant pairing (akin to [Goodman and Kruskal's gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodman_and_Kruskal%27s_gamma))? Or would that obscure vital features of the correspondence?

Comment: @R.M. That sounds very interesting, thanks for the ideas, I will look into those links. Do you by any chance know if there's an easy way of implementing that in R?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone The hard thing about the data is that there are lots of minima and maxima, so there's not really a way to look at it manually. Also, I'd like a method that is generally applicable also if I look at the same simulations and actuals but then for another time frame in the past (which will hence have minima/maxima at different places), as I'm trying to backtest at multiple times in the past which model performed best.

Comment: Perhaps formulate objective function in terms he numbers of minima and maxima vs. truth, and location of maxima and minima vs. truth. You' have to decide how to do that. What if one model has almost perfect location of most all minima and maxima, but is missing one altogether vs. another model which has correct numbers of minimna and maxima, but not as accurate on locations? You have to figure out what you want along those lines. Do you care only about number and locations of minima and maxima or do you also care about shale between them/? Could be more concrete w/ specific fitted model types.